# MySQL: OPTIMIZE after TRUNCATE?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, truncate

Using MySQL (either InnoDB or MyISAM tables--I have both), if I `TRUNCATE` a table and then `LOAD DATA INFILE`, should I issue an `OPTIMIZE TABLE` call after the `LOAD`? It's unclear to me if this is a helpful action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## MyISAM

You should perform this as follows:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mydb.myisam_mytable;
ALTER TABLE mydb.myisam_table DISABLE KEYS;
LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO mydb.myisam_table ... ;
ALTER TABLE mydb.myisam_table ENABLE KEYS;
ANALYZE TABLE mydb.myisam_table;
```

The `DISABLE KEYS` will allow the `LOAD DATA INFILE` perform a linear building of the PRIMARY KEY and any UNIQUE indexes.

The `ENABLE KEYS` will perform a linear building of all non-unique (secondary) indexes.

Skip doing `DISABLE KEYS` and `ENABLE KEYS` if there are no secondary indexes.

`ANALYZE TABLE` compiles index statistics (the last step of an `OPTIMIZE TABLE`)

## InnoDB

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` would essentially do a reload of the table a second time. That's like doing `LOAD DATA INFILE` twice.

In other words doing this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO mydb.innodb_table ... ;
OPTIMIZE TABLE mydb.innodb_table;
```

would mechanically behave like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ... INTO mydb.innodb_table ... ;
ALTER TABLE mydb.innodb_table ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

No real benefit in the case of InnoDB. Just the `LOAD DATA INFILE` would be adequate.